# Gaussian Elimination Minimum Cost Circulation

Tags: algorithms, graphs

In Eva Tardos Strongly polynomial Minimum cost Circulation Algorithm , Step 1 states projecting d, the cost function on a subspace X where flow is 0 for all tight Edges. Also we define an incidence matrix A for all non-tight edges with values{ 1,-1,0} accordingly.
later it is proved that the projection is d(E-T(G))+πA and since it is orthogonal to A we get the following equation:

[d(E-T(G))+πA]A^Transpose=0

How do I compute π using Gaussian Elimination?

Comment: Apparently the method that you're referring to is from [_A strongly polynomial minimum cost circulation algorithm_](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02579369) (1985), which aims to solve a [minimum-cost flow problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).  Apparently Tardos's method isn't how folks do this anymore; rather, Wikipedia suggests a [network simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_simplex_algorithm).

Comment: The notation in the paper's pretty archaic; can you write out the variable definitions?